# facebook Ads Api DEEP COPY/EXPORT CAMAPIGN-ADSETS-ADS DATA

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I need to deep copy campaign from one Account to another ads account.
ais their any way to Deep copy the campaign? or Their is any way to Export/Import the data?

This is the url to copy Campaigns but it only copy Campaigns of only one account.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/Campaign_id/copies
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to implement, but mb the following links will help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/copies/#async

Comment: Its basically a clients requirement he has multiple add accounts and he want to copy one ad account campaigns,adsets and ads into his another account.
The link you have mention it duplicate the campaigns into same account.

Comment: facebook api doesn't allow to duplicate the campaign from one account to another. i actually manage to duplicate the campaigns into another account manually.